# How can I call a variable from a view to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this input inside a form in a view that is rendered by the `home#home` controller.

```
<input type="hidden" id="idG" name="idGrade" value=<%=gradework.id%>></input>
```

How can I call from the controller the variable `idGrade` that I put in name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call it from a controller, but you can send it to a controller as a parameter via `POST` (using a `form`, or `ajax`, for example) or via `GET` (as string in the url).

For example, if you want to send it to `gradeworks#create`, you could do something like this:

```
<form action="/gradeworks" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="idG" name="idGrade" value="<%= gradework.id %>">
  <input type="submit">
<form>
```

And, in your `gradeworks` controller:

```
def create
  @gradework_id = params[:idGrade]
  # more code...
end
```

So you send the form with the value (or values) to your controller and then you read those values from the `params` hash.

Comment: I had it inside a form, but I did not know how to call it in the controller, thank you very much